# Registering user to Openfire XMPP server with servlet?

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish, xmpp, openfire

I'm very new to XMPP. I wrote a program that creates a client account in openfire. Now I want to turn that program into a Java EE Servlet.

When I use the same code I got an error.

Please tell me how to use Smack in a Java EE Servlet and also tell me how to install xmppjca to a GlassFish server using binaries.

Comment: Please start by including the details of the error your received.

Answer (score 2):

You could try installing User Service plugin and then create users using a small webservice.
Examples here:
http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/plugins/userservice/readme.html